# SQL Server triggers in Northwind: Not working code

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Here are the instructions: after creating the `ChangeLog` table, create a trigger on the `Employees` table for UPDATE. Use this trigger to monitor the `PayRate` column, and if the `PayRate` of an employee gets changed, have the trigger insert a row into the `ChangeLog` table with the appropriate data. [Use the function `suser_sname()` to get the user making the change and insert this into the user column.]

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PayRate_Change 
ON Employees
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EmpID int;
    DECLARE @OldRate money;
    DECLARE @NewRate money;

    IF UPDATE (PsyRate)
        SELECT @EmpID = (SELECT @EmpID FROM inserted)

    SELECT @OldRate = (SELECT PsyRate FROM deleted)
    SELECT @NewRate = (SELECT PsyRate FROM inserted)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChangeLog](EmpID, ChangedBy, DateChanged, OldRate, NewRate)
    VALUES (@EmpID, suser_sname(), getdate(), @OldRate, @NewRate);

    PRINT 'The PayRate was changed from "' + @OldRate + '" to "' + @NewRate + '"'
END

UPDATE Employees
SET PsyRate = PsyRate * 1.2
WHERE LastName ='King';
```

When ever I do the update statement at the bottom I get an error :

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure PayRate_Change, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Northwind is a SQL Server database.  The code looks like SQL Server code.  I changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger should look more like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PayRate_Change ON Employees AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ChangeLog (EmpID, CHangedBy, DateChanged, OldRate, NewRate)
        SELECT i.empid, suser_sname(), getdate(), d.PsyRate, i.PsyRate
        FROM inserted i JOIN
             deleted d
             ON i.empid = d.empid AND
                d.PsyRate <> i.PsyRate;  -- does not take `NULL`s into account

END;
```

The most important change is that you are no longer assuming that only one row is changed -- so the code no longer has a bug waiting to happen.  This is a very important part of writing triggers in SQL Server.  Do not assume that `inserted` or `deleted` has only one row.